# CiviCRM Dashboard endless loading… + Warning: file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect

Tags: wordpress, dashboard

Please help me to solve this issue:

CiviCRM Dashboard endless loading… + Warning: file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect.

Warning: file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/wp-includes/version.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/user:/tmp:/var/tmp:/opt/php-5.5/pear:/usr/local/bin:/etc/pki/tls/certs) in /home/user/public_html/wp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/WordPress.php on line 471

Above, I changed my real user login for “user”.

I use shared hosting by hostinger.com, where I have no access outside of public_html folder. It is not possible to access Linux system folders like: usr, /opt, /etc. Is it needed to CiviCRM to access that folders?

Apache 2.4, PHP 5.5.35, memory allocated 256 MB, MYSQL 5.6

I installed Wordpress 4.5.3 fast and easy by some graphic installer at the hosting panel. Then, I installed civicrm-4.7.8-wordpress.zip downloading it by the Wordpress plugin installer. CiviCRM installed and activated, I run civiCRM installer. CiviCRM Installer sad “Youŕe ready to install! - Database version and connection settings have been verified and look correct!” All requrements were Ok. Then, I pressed the button “Check Requirements and Install CiviCRM” without sample data. CiviCRM was “successfull” installed, but there was an error: no CiviCRM menus, Dashboard (endless) loading…  … never finished.
At the top, the permanent message: “Warning: file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/wp-includes/version.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/user:/tmp:/var/tmp:/opt/php-5.5/pear:/usr/local/bin:/etc/pki/tls/certs) in /home/user/public_html/wp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/WordPress.php on line 471”

“System Status: Error: Cron Not Running, Configure Default Mailbox, Complete Setup”.

Then, I uninstalled Wordpress, reinstalled it, and did some configurations every time I reinstalled it before install CiviCRM.

I edited the settings, media(miscellaneous), to only “wp-content/uploads” without quotes, or the respective temp folder, at any time a tried a new install, did logof, login again and a new CiviCRM install with other plugins disabled.

In wp-config.php, I edited line 62 by changing “define('WP_TEMP_DIR',dirname(**FILE**).'/wp-content/uploads');” for “DEFINE('WP_TEMP_DIR','../tmp')” or “define('WP_TEMP_DIR', dirname(**FILE**) . '/wp-content/temp/');” and simultaneously creating the respective temp or tmp folder. Hostinger accounts have no tmp folder by default.

Don’t matter what I do, CiviCRM installation always fails in Wordpress.

version.php

/**
 * Holds the WordPress DB revision, increments when changes are made to the WordPress DB schema.
 *
 * @global int $wp_db_version
 */
$wp_db_version = 36686;

/**
 * Holds the TinyMCE version
 *
 * @global string $tinymce_version
 */
$tinymce_version = '4310-20160418';

/**
 * Holds the required PHP version
 *
 * @global string $required_php_version
 */
$required_php_version = '5.2.4';

/**
 * Holds the required MySQL version
 *
 * @global string $required_mysql_version
 */
$required_mysql_version = '5.0';

$wp_local_package = 'pt_BR';

Comment: Looking at the file and the line in question, CRM_Utils_System_WordPress is simply checking for version.php. This file should be (based on the details above in:

    /home/user/public_html/wp-includes/version.php

In your error message you referenced:

    /home/wp-includes/version.php

That should not be returned at all, especially since later you refer to the path to CRM_Utils_System_WordPress as

    /home/user/public_html/wp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/WordPress.php

Can you verify the real path to wp-includes?

Comment: Hello Kevin. Thank you for your help!

The real path to version.php is: "public_html/wp/wp-includes/version.php"

Wordpress was installed in directory '/public_html/wp"

In Wordpress menu /settings/general/ wordpress address is filled correctly as: mydomain/wp

It seems that CiviCRM ignores 'wp' directory. I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: I use shared hosting by hostinger.com, where I have no access outside of public_html folder. It is not possible to access Linux system folders like: usr, /opt, /etc. Is it needed for CiviCRM to work by accessing that folders?

Answer (score 1):

As your comment details, WordPress is installed in it's own directory `public_html/wp`

Currently, CiviCRM has issues with WP in it's own directory as detailed here:  https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRM/WordPress+installed+in+its+own+directory+issues

There are some patches, but at this time a standard install of CiviCRM will not work unless WP is installed in the webroot and not in it's own directory.

Comment: Ok. I removed wordpress and databank, reinstalled it at webroot and installed CiviCRM-4.7.8 in English. CiviCRM activated, I tried to enter Civi Dashboard to do the first settings. The same messange was showed again, at this time, without /wp subdirectory: "Warning: file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/wp-includes/version.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/user:/tmp:/var/tmp:/opt/php-5.5/pear:/usr/local/bin:/etc/pki/tls/certs) in /home/user/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/WordPress.php on line 471"